# How to remove env variable in current shell dynamically?

Tags: bash, compilation, environment-variables, conda

I have installed miniconda on my system which creates various env variables. This lead to duplication of paths to binaries and libraries in both on system and conda path. This is not an issue for me. However, when I try to compile certain libraries, it picks up the binaries or libraries from conda path rather than system variables. This lead to compile error.

Here is what I have in env:

```
PATH=/home/sundar/miniconda3/bin:/home/sundar/miniconda3/condabin:/home/sundar/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/bin:/home/sundar/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2@global/bin:/home/sundar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/home/sundar/.rvm/bin:/home/sundar/.rvm/bin:/home/sundar/.local/bin
CONDA_EXE=/home/sundar/miniconda3/bin/conda
_CE_CONDA=
CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=/home/sundar/miniconda3/bin/python
CONDA_SHLVL=1
CONDA_PREFIX=/home/sundar/miniconda3
CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=base
CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER=(base) 
GSETTINGS_SCHEMA_DIR_CONDA_BACKUP=
GSETTINGS_SCHEMA_DIR=/home/sundar/miniconda3/share/glib-2.0/schemas
XML_CATALOG_FILES=file:///home/sundar/miniconda3/etc/xml/catalog file:///etc/xml/catalog
PROJ_DATA=/home/sundar/miniconda3/share/proj
```

I would like to remove all the paths which are matching 'conda' key word dynamicall from terminal. I do not wish to remove from `~/.bashrc` or profile file.

I am aware that follwing command would do the trick:-

```
export PATH=${PATH/'/path/to/be/removed/'/}
```

But I would like to make it dynamic so that it can be used in any system and not specific to mine. Since I would be using bash for my compilation process, I can use this technique to unset the variables before proceeding and avaid compile errors.

**Edit 1**

What I want finally is for example, below PATH variable

```
PATH=/home/sundar/miniconda3/bin:/home/sundar/miniconda3/condabin:/home/sundar/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/bin:/home/sundar/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2@global/bin:/home/sundar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/home/sundar/.rvm/bin:/home/sundar/.rvm/bin:/home/sundar/.local/bin
```

should change in to

```
PATH=/home/sundar/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/bin:/home/sundar/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2@global/bin:/home/sundar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/home/sundar/.rvm/bin:/home/sundar/.rvm/bin:/home/sundar/.local/bin
```

You can see that path to dirs `/home/sundar/miniconda3/bin:/home/sundar/miniconda3/condabin` are removed from `$PATH`.

In addition, any refernce to conda or CONDA variable is not required to be set. Finally, the ultimate aim is that any file/ dir path contain "**miniconda3**" is to be removed from the env vaiable.

Comment: If you don't want to pick up libraries from your conda environment, then the natural thing to do would be to [deactivate your conda environment](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/4.6.1/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#deactivating-an-environment) before building.

Comment: I think you will need to use `eval` for this. That's the only way to assign variables dynamically.

Comment: please update the question to show the expected results; it's not clear (to me) what should happen to the `CONDA*` variables, eg, should `CONDA_SHLVL` be unset or left alone (since it doesn't contain the lowercase 'conda' in its value)?

Comment: @Barmar, Updated thae post with expected result.

Comment: `any refernce to conda or CONDA variable is not required to be set.` What is "reference to conda or conda variable"? What is a reference?

Comment: @KamilCuk I guess they mean any variable name or value containing `conda`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want finally is for example, below PATH variable

To remove all `:` separated elements inside `PATH` containing the string `conda`, I would lazily just do:

```
PATH=$(<<<"$PATH" tr ':' '\n' | grep -v conda | tr '\n' ':')
```

But to be bug free I would rather go with something along:

```
newpath=""
while IFS= read -r -d: i; do
    case "$i" in
    *conda*) ;;
    *) newpath+="${newpath:+:}$i"
    esac
done < <(printf "%s" "$PATH")
export "PATH=$newpath"
```

> any refernce to conda or CONDA variable is not required to be set

To remove all variable which contain CONDA in the name, you can just do:

```
 unset $(compgen -v | grep CONDA)
```

To remove all variables which contain the string conda in the value, you have to iterate over all variable values:

```
 for i in $(compgen -v); do
     case "${!i}" in
     *conda*) unset "$i"; ;;
     esac
 done
```

Word splitting and filename expansions can be ignored here, because `compgen` has to output sane outputs. Using `while IFS= read -r` would be better to silence shellcheck. And we can squeeze to one loop anyway.

```
vars=$(compgen -v)
while IFS= read -r i; do
     case "$i" in
     *CONDA*) unset "$i"; ;;
     *)
         case "${!i}" in
         *conda*) unset "$i"; ;;
         esac
         ;;
     esac
done <<<"$vars"
```

Comment: Your solution worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- for file listings (eg, `XML_CATALOG_FILES`) we don't have to worry about directory/file names containing white space
- OP obtains the list of variables via something like `env | grep -i conda`
- all variable names containing the string `CONDA` or `conda` are to be `unset`
- all values containing the string `conda` are to be removed

Setup:

```
$ cat env.list
export CONDA_PATH=/home/sundar/miniconda3/bin:/home/sundar/miniconda3/condabin:/home/sundar/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/bin:/home/sundar/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2@global/bin:/home/sundar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/home/sundar/.rvm/bin:/home/sundar/.rvm/bin:/home/sundar/.local/bin
export CONDA_EXE=/home/sundar/miniconda3/bin/conda
export _CE_CONDA=
export CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=/home/sundar/miniconda3/bin/python
export CONDA_SHLVL=1
export CONDA_PREFIX=/home/sundar/miniconda3
export CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=base
export CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER=(base)
export GSETTINGS_SCHEMA_DIR_CONDA_BACKUP=
export GSETTINGS_SCHEMA_DIR=/home/sundar/miniconda3/share/glib-2.0/schemas
export XML_CATALOG_FILES="file:///home/sundar/miniconda3/etc/xml/catalog file:///etc/xml/catalog"
export PROJ_DATA=/home/sundar/miniconda3/share/proj
```

**NOTE:** I've renamed OP's `PATH` to `CONDA_PATH` so that I don't mess up my own `PATH`

One (verboase) `bash` attempt:

```
########
# load OP's variables into my env

. ./env.list

########
# build a list of variable names; only used to display before/after var=val pairs

var_list=( $(env | grep -i conda | cut -d= -f1) )

########

printf "\n########### before\n\n"

env | grep -f <(printf "%s\n" ${var_list[@]})

########
# actual code to unset vars or remove values;
# OP could place the following in a custom/user-defined function

while IFS='=' read -r cvar old_value
do
    # unset variables where variable name contains string "CONDA" or "conda";
    # ' && "${cvar}" != "CONDA_PATH" ' test is for my env and can be removed in OP's env

    [[ "${cvar}" =~ CONDA|conda && "${cvar}" != "CONDA_PATH" ]] &&
    unset "${cvar}" &&
    continue

    d_in=':'                                        # standard env value delimiter
    [[ "${old_value}" =~ file: ]] && d_in=' '       # delimiter for XML_CATALOG_FILES

    IFS="${d_in}" read -ra arr <<< "${old_value}"   # split old_value on delimiter and place in array arr[]

    unset new_value d_out                           # initialize some vars

    for ((i=0; i<${#arr[@]}; i++))                  # loop through array indices
    do
        [[ "${arr[i]}" =~ conda ]] && continue      # if value contains string "conda" then skip to next pass through loop else ...
        new_value="${new_value}${d_out}${arr[i]}"   # build up our new_value
        d_out="${d_in}"                             # update the output delimiter
    done

    declare -n _var="${cvar}"                       # nameref
    export _var="${new_value}"                      # set/export our new variable
done < <(env | grep -i conda)

########

printf "\n########### after\n\n"

env | grep -f <(printf "%s\n" ${var_list[@]})
```

**NOTE:** requires `bash v 4.3+` for `nameref / declare -n` support

This generates:

```
########### before

CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=base
CONDA_EXE=/home/sundar/miniconda3/bin/conda
CONDA_PATH=/home/sundar/miniconda3/bin:/home/sundar/miniconda3/condabin:/home/sundar/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/bin:/home/sundar/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2@global/bin:/home/sundar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/home/sundar/.rvm/bin:/home/sundar/.rvm/bin:/home/sundar/.local/bin
CONDA_PREFIX=/home/sundar/miniconda3
CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=/home/sundar/miniconda3/bin/python
CONDA_SHLVL=1
GSETTINGS_SCHEMA_DIR=/home/sundar/miniconda3/share/glib-2.0/schemas
GSETTINGS_SCHEMA_DIR_CONDA_BACKUP=
PROJ_DATA=/home/sundar/miniconda3/share/proj
XML_CATALOG_FILES=file:///home/sundar/miniconda3/etc/xml/catalog file:///etc/xml/catalog
_CE_CONDA=

########### after

CONDA_PATH=/home/sundar/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/bin:/home/sundar/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2@global/bin:/home/sundar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/home/sundar/.rvm/bin:/home/sundar/.rvm/bin:/home/sundar/.local/bin
GSETTINGS_SCHEMA_DIR=
PROJ_DATA=
XML_CATALOG_FILES=file:///etc/xml/catalog
```